# Silent SAML authentication?

Tags: authentication, saml

I'm trying to authenticate users with the SAML protocol.
So far I have two applications in two different identity providers (Auth0 and OneLogin) to test. I also have my service provider.
What I'm trying to do is authenticate users without redirecting them to any Identity Provider login form.
Something like this:

1. The user tries to log in to my application (made in React)
2. My server provider receives the request made by the user and sends
   the credentials (username and password) to an identity provider
   using the SAML protocol.
3. The identity provider validates the credentials, if they are
   correct, return a SAML assertion to my server provider; otherwise,
   it will return an error.
4. Depends on the identity provider's response if the content is sent
   to the user or not.

I know that it is not the intended use of SAML, but I want to know if there is a way to do it and how it will be possible.

---

Any help or advice will be well received, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how SAML works and I'm not aware of any SAML identity providers that accept the user's name and password.

It is possible to include the user's name in the SAML authn request sent to the identity provider but there's no provision for including a password.

I think there are a number of security considerations if you were to prompt a user for their credentials for one web site (ie the identity provider) at a different web site (ie service provider).

Using SAML SSO, if the user isn't already authenticated at the identity provider, it will prompt the user to login.

Comment: So, I must use the login form of the identity provider whenever the user logs in (except when they have an existing session) right? The problem is that I want this to be totally transparent to the user.

Comment: That's correct. I'm not sure how you could make this transparent to the user.

Comment: I found the ECP SAML profile that help to achieve a "transparent" authentication for the user. Hope this helps someone looking for the same. 
 "The ECP profile enables single sign-on when the Identity Provider and Service Provider cannot communicate directly. The ECP acts as the intermediary between the Service Provider and the Identity Provider." More information [here](https://docops.ca.com/ca-siteminder-federation-standalone/12-52-sp1/en/configuring/single-sign-on-configuration/enhanced-client-or-proxy-profile-overview-saml-2-0)

Comment: The problem with the ECP profile is that it's rarely used or supported. Also, I'm not sure if it will meet your requirements. It will depend very much on the support provided by the identity provider.

Comment: In some way it will comply with the requirements, it will allow me to authenticate my users without any redirection. They also told me about Keycloak (a SAML IdP that supports ECP profile). I'm going to give it a try and I'll see what happens. Thank you for you response, it was helpful.